# Trying to create nav bar in angular but it is not displaying on localhost

Tags: html, angular

I want to display nav bar using angular, I have added the code of nav bar in nav.component.html but navbar is not displaying on localhost. Please see my code and let me know if there is something wrong with the code. 
Following is nav.component.html code :

```
<header>
<div class="container">
    <a routerLink="/" class="logo">{{appTitle}}</a>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a routeLink="/"> HOME</li>
            <li><a routeLink="/about"> ABOUT US</li>
            <li><a routeLink="/"> BLOG</li>
            <li><a routeLink="/"> CONTACT</li>  
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
</header>
```

And following is code of app.component.html. Please see the following

```
 <app-nav></app-nav>
 <section>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
 </section>
```

And the following is code of nav.component.ts. Please see the following

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
 selector: 'app-nav',
 templateUrl: './nav.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./nav.component.scss']
})
export class NavComponent implements OnInit {
appTitle: string = 'myapp';
constructor() { }
ngOnInit() {
}
}
```

Currently http://localhost:4200/ is showing an blank page. I expect the navbar to be displayed.

Comment: do you have any error on the console when it displays blank? did it reload (recomplied the code after change) and ran? else create an example on [https://stackblitz.com/](https://stackblitz.com/) so people can check it

Comment: @rmjoia Sir, yes it is showing error in console. Please see the following

 :Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
Unexpected closing tag "li". It may happen when the tag has already been closed by another tag. For more info see https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#closing-elements-that-have-implied-end-tags ("

Comment: @GurpreetKaur there you have your answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
<header>
<div class="container">
    <a routerLink="/" class="logo">{{appTitle}}</a>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a routeLink="/"> HOME </a></li>
            <li><a routeLink="/about"> ABOUT US </a></li>
            <li><a routeLink="/"> BLOG </a></li>
            <li><a routeLink="/"> CONTACT </a></li>  
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
</header>
```

you're not closing the a tag on the navbar